# Is the percentage symbol a constant?

Tags: notation, percentages, unit-of-measure

1. Isn't the percentage symbol actually just a constant with the value $0.01$? As in 
   $$
   15\% = 15 \times \% = 15 \times 0.01 = 0.15.
   $$
2. Isn't every unit  actually just a constant? But why do we treat them in such a special way then?

Comment: Right, you can very well see $\%$ as a numerical constant, though culturally this would shock many people.

Comment: It is not a unit of measure; it is only a useful [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign). 15% is $\dfrac {15}{100}$. A [percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) is a number.

Comment: I agree completely that % can be considered a real number.

Comment: As the others said. I would though recommend avoiding writing $15\times \%$ as it is unusual and may confuse people.

Comment: @Taladris I never said I would write it like that. I was just wondering if it could be looked at as a value that you multiply by instead of this "special" thing. : )

Comment: Some believe that it's a map $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^*$ that assigns to $x$ the functional $x\%(y)=\frac{xy}{100}$. Not that they *know* it, but they rather perceive it. And it becomes apparent when they describe their difficulties.

Comment: Quoting the [dictionary edited by
Steven G. Krantz](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RvUoI39g2cAC&dq=DICTIONARY+OF+ALGEBRA,+ARITHMETIC,+AND+TRIGONOMETRY&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDuKD6_8_gAhXzIrkGHW2-D8QQ6AEIKTAA), "The symbol $\%$ stands for $\frac{}{100}$". From this point of view, it is not a constant but a "division by a constant".

Comment: As answered by @Paul, I think most of these answeres are missing an important point: [a percentage is a ratio or a fraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage). Seeing % as "multiply by 0.01" misses exactly this point and leads tot errors in adding and subtracting percentages  tot nominal values ($ 20 with 25% discount is $ 15 and not $ 20 - 25/100 = $ 19.75)...

Comment: I sometimes like to think of it as a postfix operator.

Comment: I would caution you about writing, for example, "$1 + \%$", as few people would understand that you mean $1.01$.

Comment: Technically yes, but since it's a unitless constant and just a simple power of ten, like deca or centi, most people won't think of it as a 'proper' unitless constant (like pi or e). And unlike π, the '%' and 'e' buttons on a calculator perform an actual operation, whereas the 'π' button just generates a constant (and overwrites the current value). So, 'xπ' does something different (and wrong) compared to 'x%'. So the answer is "it depends on whether you mean '%' the concept, the value, or operation (/calculator button)". Last, if we think percentages are unitless, try finance spreadsheets...

Comment: Another nuance is we never write '%' on its own without context e.g. '1 + %' , whereas a plain 'π', or '1 + π', is perfectly clear.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I agree with this point but would go on to say its the general idea of dimensions. There is an intrinsic dimensional nature of the unit in "$3$ metres" or "$7\%$" that just isn't captured by the number. And, as in your explanation, the value of $y$ may not practically impact operations such as $x_1\%(y)+x_2\%(y)=(x_1+x_2)\%(y)$ but $y$ is still tied to the final answer. So just because we reach the right numerical answer by considering units as algebraic variables, it doesn't mean we aren't losing something.

Comment: Terence Tao has [written about dimensional analysis](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/) on his website.  An intrepid answerer might build an answer around this exposition.  I think that the TL;DR version is something like "dimensionful numbers are elements of a tensor product of the real numbers and dimensions".

Answer (score 56):

> Isn't the percentage symbol actually just a constant with the value $0.01$?

No. If it were, all of the following would be valid constructs:

$$
30+\%\,50=30.5\\
90\,\%\,\mathrm{cm}=0.9\,\mathrm{cm}\\
2-\%=1.99\\
\%^2=0.0001
$$

The percentage symbol is a *unit*. When converting between units, it's easy to treat them as constants that represent the conversion ratio, and multiply (for example, the $\mathrm{m}$ unit can be thought of as a constant equal to $100\,\mathrm{cm}$, in $2\,\mathrm{m}=2(100\,\mathrm{cm})=200\,\mathrm{cm}$). But that isn't the same as saying they're "just constants", as they represent more than that. A unit is not just a ratio, it's a distance or a weight or an amount of time.

This is less obvious with $\%$ because it's a [dimensionless unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity), representing something more abstract like "parts of a whole" rather than a physical property like mass or surface area. $1\,\%$ is "one one-hundredth of a thing", measuring an amount of something, anything, often something with its own units. A similarly dimensionless unit is the "degree", where $1^\circ$ is "one three-hundred-sixtieth of the way around". Another one is the "cycle", as in "one $\mathrm{Mhz}$ is one million cycles per second". Things like "wholes", "turns", and "cycles" are more abstract than inches or grams, but when applied they still represent tangible measurements, so they aren't any less powerful when treated as units.

---

> I mean, I guess every unit is actually just a constant, but why do we treat them in such a special way then?

What then would you say the "constant" is that is represented by "inch", or "second", or "ounce"? Would these ideas not have clear numeric values if every unit were simply a constant?

Again, a unit is not just a constant, it represents something more. I don't have exact vocabulary for this, but I would say a unit is an "amount" of a "dimension". The dimension can be time, space, energy, mass, etc. To even begin to treat a unit as a constant, we need to consider it in terms of a *different unit in the same dimension*. For example, the unit "millisecond" amounts to different constants depending on whether we think about it in terms of a *second* ($0.001$), *hour* ($2.77778\times10^{-7}$), *microsecond* ($1000$), etc. This constant is not intrinsic to the units themselves, as it only arises when comparing to other units.

Comment: By this logic, the "percentage conversion factor" (which does not have a symbol) _would_ be a constant with a value of $0.01$, much like feet to inches has a conversion factor of $\frac{1}{12}$. Having symbols for these constants would be unmanageable. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Andy Yes, that makes sense - the technical term for those conversion factor(s) is "constant(s) of proportionality".

Comment: I agree with the precise answer you've given, but it is relevant to note that the name "percent" was chosen as if it were a unit. "Per cent" means "per 100", which is the verbal equivalent of **/100**, i.e. [15%] = [15 per 100]  = [15/100]. For everyday usage, one can think of it as a constant, but it isn't a constant to a very precise degree (which is explained in this answer).

Comment: Come to think of it, can we not consider **cm** to be the equivalent constant of **m/100**? It relies on a predefined but unknown constant (what is a meter?) but any ratio thereof (such as cm, km, ...) can be defined accurately. Similarly, isn't **%** simply the constant expression of **"the whole"/100**? While "the whole" shouldn't be defined as the numerical 1, if you assume that "the whole" is an unspecified constant, then % should be able to be defined as a ratio of "the whole".

Comment: @Flater Exactly. I tend to think of "the whole" as a sort of "meta-unit", since it can be applied to any unit-ed value and doesn't really represent its own dimension like other units do. Really the constant "the whole" would be defined as "the value you're taking a percentage of", but if you instead define it as 1 and then multiply by said value, you happen to get the same result, so either interpretation will do in practice.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the above... in particular $90\%\,\text{cm}=0.9\,\text{cm}$.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy 90%cm doesn't make any sense. "nine tenths of centimeters" is not a valid measurement. If you said "90% of 1cm" it would be correct, but in its current form it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: It does to me because to my mind $\text{cm}=1\text{ cm}$.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy I've never seen that notation. I'd be extremely surprised if that was common.

Comment: I find it very useful for conversion of units

Comment: You seem to assume that a constant has to be a number, while a unit can be something else. I'd argue that that is not how the word "constant" is used in practice. For instance the Plank constant or the speed of light are constants, but they are not numbers..same with the meter and the second.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, for calculations you can use $\%=\frac{1}{100}$. Of course what is meant by the symbol is an interpretation as "parts of hundred", i.e. as percentage of a given amount.

Comment: % means "per hundred", which makes it an *operation*, not a *constant*.  The OP is correct except for "15 x %".

Answer (score 10):

There are some exceptions. Take for example $20 + 50\%$. This is often interpreted to be equal to $30$, while $20 + 50 \cdot 0.01 = 20.5$.

There is some discussion about whether $20 + 50\%$ is a valid notation. But sometimes it is used and Google and Wolfram Alpha interpret it as $20\cdot 1.5$.

I'm also thinking about $50\%^2$. I don't think you'll see this notation (and you shouldn't use it), but just as a thought experiment: Is this $0.25$ or $0.005$?

Comment: But the convention that $20+50\%=30$ leads to bizarre results such as $20 + 50\% - 50\% = 15$ or $20 + 100\% - 100\% = 0$.

Comment: 20 + 50% does not mean anything per se. Seeing the 20 as 100% is understandable, but not guaranteed. +50% does not instantly imply *150% as gandalf61 illustrated.

Comment: @gandalf61  I agree with you. But the notation $x+y\%$ is not uncommon when weights of products, tolerance of resistors, density of chemical solutions, etc. are reported. If you worry about the algebra, then the algebra is not associative which is true about many other mathematical objects as well. I think this is a very good answer. (+1).

Comment: AFAIK, many pocket calculators use this convention as well.

Comment: My point is that the $+$ sign in this convention is *not* addition. It is shorthand for a different operator $\oplus$ which can be defined as $a \oplus b = a \times (1+b)$. With this interpretation $20 \oplus 50\% = 20 \times (1+50\%) = 20 \times (1+50 \times 0.01) = 20 \times 1.5 = 30$ and we are good.

Comment: @gandalf61 I know. And that's exactly why I said it's not associative. Addition is associative. I was just saying that the OP's answer is actually a very good one because it had been downvoted when I saw this post.

Comment: I'm on the fence on this one. I'd be willing to upvote it if it were worded more as "this is a common interpretation" rater than treating this as the clear meaning. Pointing out that the OP's interpretation works only for multiplication is an important point.

Comment: Pointing out how prominent this is in engineering might be a good addition to this. I see resistors rated 1kΩ±1% all the time, capacitors that say 47μF±20%, and so on. This matches the interpretation Paul's answer uses.

Comment: The "%²" is more commonly known as the "basis point(s)", or "bp".  It is one percent of one percent.  Similarly, "%³" is more commonly known as the "part(s) per million", or "ppm".

Comment: @gandalf61 But it is common to talk of adding 10% but that really means multiplying by $1.10$.  That adding 10% and then subtracting 10% does not return you to the original value is part of the reason that % frequently causes confusion.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't say that $\%$ has a value. You can think of $\%$ as "multiply by $\frac{1}{100}"$ as a sort of postfix in the same way as you can think of the "kilo-" prefix as "multiply by $1000$".

So 
$$
5\% = 5\ (\text{multiply by} \ \frac{1}{100})=\frac{5}{100}=0.05
$$ 
in the same way as
$$
2 \ \text{kilograms}=2 \ (\text{multiply by $1000$})\text{ grams}= 2000 \ \text{grams}
$$

I usually teach my students this way and I found it to work just fine.

Comment: Um... the $-$ prefix ($-x$/$-1x$/$x-2x$) sounds better to me as a prefix example, LOL. Also, $!$ is a good postfix example (if we disregard the double, triple, etc. factorials). :P

Answer (score 7):

The percent sign is an abbreviation: just substitute "$\color{red}\%$" by "${}\color{red}{\cdot\frac{1}{100}}$", that's all.  So for example: $15\color{red}{\%}=15\color{red}{\cdot\frac{1}{100}}=0.15$. Or the other way round: $1.23=123\color{red}{\cdot\frac{1}{100}}=123\color{red}{\%}$.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it really depends. In Chinese schools, students are told that $100\%=1,40\%=2/5$, so % is a constant. In the UK examination system, it appears that % is treated as a unit. Students are NOT expected to write the above two expressions.

However, it is agreed around the world that you should not write something like "$250\%$ liters of water".

So it is a good idea to think of it as a constant, but not write it as a constant.

Other units like cm, mm, kg are like the basis of a vector space or something or the imaginary unit $i^2=1$. The are NOT even like usual numbers because they cannot be added together.

Comment: I also leads to incongruities like $5\%$ of two hundred Dollars is $5\%\$$ ?!

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Aside from what seems to be typo, I don't see anything wrong with that usage. If I wanted to translate the equation 5% * 15 EUR = 75% EUR into words, I'd say "five percent of fifteen euros is seventy-five percent of a euro," which sounds fine to me. Similarly, I'd read 5% * 20 EUR = 100% EUR as "five percent of twenty euros is one hundred percent of a euro—that is, one whole euro."

Comment: @Vectornaut: no typo.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If there's no typo, I'm having trouble understanding what you wrote. Do we agree that 5%\$ = 5% * \$1 = 0.05 * \$1 = \$0.05?

Comment: Wait a minute—the MathJax processor was doing funny things to the dollar signs in my last post until I escaped them. Maybe your initial post is displaying differently for me than for you?

Comment: @Vectornaut: my bad, I should have written $1000\%\$$ (or $1000\$\%$ ?)

Comment: Conversion from percentage expressions to fractions is a standard part of the UK examinations.  UK students are expected to be able to convert 40% = 2/5 and make comparisons  "which is larger 30% or 1/3?"

Comment: cm + cm = 2cm, in the same way cm * cm = cm², although by convention you'd put a numeral in there for clarity. cm + mm = cm + mm * (cm / 10mm) = 1.1cm = 11mm. Things like cm + kg are undefined in most cases though.

Comment: Even weird phrases like "250% liters" sound natural to me in some circumstances. For example, if my favorite ice cream recipe has a 90% overrun, I know one liter of mix will make 190% of a liter of ice cream!

Answer (score 4):

1. > Isn't every unit actually just a constant?

   Every constant is a quantity (whether with or without a unit); thus,
   Celsius is not a constant.

   > Isn't the percentage symbol actually just a constant with the value $0.01$?

   While it may appear that $$\%\;:=\;0.01,$$ this is a *false
   definition* since neither $(\%-8)$ nor $\dfrac7\%$ are really
   meaningful.

   In other words, $\%$ is **not a constant**.
2. But $\%$ is **not a unit** either, since it does not specify any
   physical quantity ($7\%$ is not a physical quantity).
3. I agree with Lehs's answer: $\%$ is **a postfix operator** in the
   sense that
   \begin{align}x\%\:\::=\;\;&x\div100\\=\;\;&x\times0.01.\end{align}
4. While $$100+10\%+30\%$$ is frequently interpreted as equalling
   [$143$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=100%2B10%25%2B30%25)
   instead of $100.4,$ this is merely an abuse of notation.
5. I'd say that $90\%\,\textrm{cm}$ is an odd-looking intermediate
   step, like $7\,\textrm{cm}\,\textrm{cm}.$

---

When a quantity's value changes from $a$ to $b,$ its *percentage change* $$\dfrac{b-a}{|a|}\times100\%$$ means its relative change expressed a percentage. The word ‘percentage’ in the phrase *percentage change*, unlike the symbol ‘$\%$’, is not a postfix operator.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to think about units or dimensional analysis, then probably it is best to interpret 15% as

$$ 15\% = \frac{\text{$15$ units of X}}{\text{$100$ units of X}} $$

(I would read this as "15 units of X per 100 units of X".) For example, the [Wikipedia page on dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Percentages_and_derivatives) gives the example of debt-to-GDP ratio.
  $$ 90\% \text{ debt-to-GDP} = \frac{\text{$90$ dollars of debt}}{\text{per $100$ dollars of GDP}} $$

Here both the top and bottom are dollars. But they are two different dollar measurements. So even though the percentage is a dimensionless quantity (dollars/dollars), keeping the units in mind may be wise. Similarly

$$ 10\% \text{ full} = \frac{\text{$10$ liters of water}}{\text{per $100$ liters of container}} . $$

and so on. (edit) So for example, if you want to do a calculation like "How many liters of water are in a 2-gallon container that is 10% full", you do

$$ \text{$2$ gallons of container} ~ \cdot ~ \frac{\text{$3.78$ liters of container}}{\text{$1$ gallon of container}} ~ \cdot ~ \frac{\text{$10$ liters of water}}{\text{$100$ liters of container}} . $$

Of course you could have also done

$$ \text{$2$ gallons of container} ~ \cdot ~ \frac{\text{$10$ gallons of water}}{\text{$100$ gallons of container}} ~ \cdot ~ \frac{\text{$3.78$ liters of water}}{\text{$1$ gallon of water}} ~ \cdot . $$

Answer (score 2):

I think of $\cdot\%$ as an *operation* that divides the argument by $100$ and multiplies it with the *reference value* $u$ representing a whole, i. e. $x\% = x\frac{u}{100}$. As such it is actually underdetermined as the reference is implied in the non-mathematical text and not part of the notation.

For example if I give you a $5\%$ discount, the reference unit is implied to be your total, which could be $200\$$ in this example, in which case $5\%=10\$$ (note the unit!)

One could write $\%^u$ to specify the reference unit, such that in the above example $5\%^{200\$}=10\$$, although that would not be commonly understood.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has a universally agreed nature.(Symbol,constant,or Unit, or else?) Even though it might have had a single nature at the moment it was created, after a long time usage by people, with non-mathematicans as the majority, its nature might be different among different people's point of view.

In my opinion, I would regard '%' equivalent to the phrase 'out of 100'. That means 15% is read as '15 out of 100' . However, I am pretty sure someone else will have his own interpretation on '%' which leads no contradiction to mine.

Answer (score 1):

It's often convenient to write $x\%$ for $x/100$. The notation $xy$ is also used for the product of $x$ and $y$ (whether numbers, functions, elements of a group, etc.), and these give the same result if you formally set $\% = 1/100$. On the other hand, it would be bizarre to write "$1/\%$ is divisible by $5$" or "$\% + \sqrt{\%} = 0.11$", etc. There's nothing inherently wrong with abusing notation; I have no problem writing $0$ for the integer $0$, the real number $0$, the zero function, the zero element in a vector space, etc. But there's also nothing particularly noteworthy or profound in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

It's a postfix operator. A function written after the argument, $x\%=x/100$, instead of before the argument as in normal prefix notation $f(x)$ or $\Delta x$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can think of it both ways.

It’s a symbol for “parts of a hundred” that happens to have a constant value behind it, and at the same time it’s a constant that happens to have a symbolic meaning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a constant.  It can be thought of as a unit if you like, but is probably best thought of as merely a syntax.  A phrasing I find effective is to say that they are different spellings of a number.

The reason it is not a constant is because it cannot be used in all situations where a constant could be used.  For example, $100x$ cannot be meaningfully written as $\frac{x}{\%}$.  Were $\%$ to be a constant, that would be a reasonable thing to write.  It would be as reasonable as writing $\frac{x}{\pi}$.

You can get away with thinking of percents as units.  Like with your approach of treating it as a constant, the math tends to work out.  However, it doesn't really work well as a unit in general.  While the axiomization of units is still an open problem, it is typically not true that $100\ m = 1\ \frac{m}{\%}$ or $1\ m = 100\ m\cdot  \%$.  This makes it an awkward sort of unit.

I do see "%" used as a unit from time to time, but it's typically shorthand for a particular percentage.  I might see a graph of a chemical reaction efficiency written as "%/mol".  Indeed, this is using "%" as a unit, but in such a graph it would really be a shorthand for "percent efficiency of the reaction."  The same graph might instead be labeled with "%yield/mol" without really changing the meaning any.  In this case, I think it is clear that "%" is not really acting as a unit in the way you might be used to.  It's really just a letter, no different than "a" or "q."

Instead, perhaps the most reliable way of treating percents is as an alternate spelling for a number when writing it down.  This is a nuanced difference: it suggests that 10% and 0.1 are not just equal, they are in fact merely two ways of writing down the same number.  This would be no different than how a programmer might write `0x1F` to denote the number 31 in a base-16 notation, how a Chinese person might elect to write 三十一 to denote the same number, or how we might write "thirty one."  They are merely different ways of writing the same number.

This is a subtle difference, but sometimes it can be helpful.  For example, at some point you will come across the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) that 0.9999.... = 1.0.  This proof is very disconcerting at first, because you assume 0.9999... and 1.0 are two distinct numbers, so they could never be equal.  But when you really dig into the meaning of that funny little "..." symbol, you discover there's a better way to think of it.  "0.9999..." and "1.0" are simply two spellings of the same number.  One relies on an infinite series to acquire its meaning, while the other does not, but they mean the same number.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is just a *notation* i.e. a way of expressing numbers, e.g.

$0.01 = 1\% =10^{-2} = 1\text{e-}02$

Which would also explain why it is said to be *[dimensionless](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity)*.

At least Excel-like apps agree on that matter,

[image]